# can i Pass gesture recogniser in a notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am sending a notification from one class to another to call a method using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotification:[
                       NSNotification notificationWithName:@"gestureIsOn"
                       object: self
                       ]
     ];
```

WhatI want to achieve here is to receive the notification in another class but also passing the UIGestureRecognizer to find which view it is, as the class receiving the notification contains 4 different views. I already tried to implement the receiving of the notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ]addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleGestures::) name:@"gestureIsOn"
                                               object:nil];
```

and call the method `handleGestures`:

```
-(void)handleGestures:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender :(NSNotification *)notification{

if(sender.view == view1)
do something

}
```

Tried to use double :: in my observer notification but this causing an error of `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'`

Thanks in advance to everyone that spend time reading this.

Comment: could you paste more Log of this?

Comment: i can't since I tried to keep the question simple and changed my class/variable names to match the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send it like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"gestureIsOn"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:@{@"recognizer":recognizer}];
```

And on the receiving side:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = notification.userInfo[@"recognizer"];
```